# php PDO - Do you bind all parms?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was always wondering if it is good practice to bind entire list of values. For example I have to following query:

```sql
INSERT INTO messages 
  (thread_id,message,from_id,to_id,to_viewed,notified,from_deleted,to_deleted,created)
  SELECT :threadId,:msg,:fromId,:toId,0,0,0,0,:createdTime FROM messages 
    WHERE thread_id = :threadId AND to_id=:toId LIMIT 1
```

In this case would have any sense to bind also `notified`, `from_deleted` and `to_deleted` fields since this is static value, always 0 when inserting new msg?

---

I need to modify my question. I know that for security reason there is not reason to bind also fields/values that are not generated from user. In my case not reason to bind fileds `notified`, `from_deleted` and `to_deleted` because they are always 0. But my real question is should I bind those fields for other reasons (cache). Will mysql cache entire query statement or only binded parms?

Comment: Which of the queries are you trying to run? You have part of an insert query followed by an incorrect select query

Comment: Why do you think it is incorrect? I use this query to insert message only if thread_id is related to this user. In this case I don't need extra query to verify if this tread_id belongs to this user.

Comment: Right. I didn't realize it's a subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really only necessary to as you say bind the parameters (a prepared query) of variables that are from an external source (which you should also strip out html characters, scripts). When you do a prepared query PDO will convert quotes to prevent a sql injection. You can just put your static variables straight into the query because you (developer) know that it's safe for a 0 or 1 to be looked for or even some static string for that matter. The rest is just a matter of having a syntactically correct query.

You can run this query to insert a test row by using sequelpro, phpmyadmin, the mysql cli or any other sql utility (assuming you are running mysql)

```
INSERT INTO messages 
  (thread_id,message,from_id,to_id,to_viewed,notified,from_deleted,to_deleted,created)
  VALUES (1, 'Blah', 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, '2012-07-21');
```

PDO Example

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE thread_id = :threadId AND to_id=:toId LIMIT 1');
    $sth->execute(array(':threadId' => $id, ':toId' => $to_id));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Not just the user, data from any external source that you do not have direct control over should be treated as hostile. I have web services etc in mind.

Comment: But aren't there also some other advantages of prepared queries, which are not related only to security?

Comment: Yes. PreparedStatements are compiled within the database engine and can be reused later from cache (unless it gets thrown out of the cache of course)

Comment: So it could be said that your answer is not correct, and it would be correct to also use prepared statement for fields notified, from_deleted and to_deleted, right?

Comment: What? It's just an example of using PDO

Comment: You said "only necessary to as you say bind the parameters (a prepared query) of variables that are from an external source ". But that means fields from internal source won't get any benefit about cache if you bind only external source parms. Or maybe I am wrong, because I thought that only bind parms are cached.

Comment: Meaning you get variable v from source A and you run a query on your database using the value of v, you can't trust the value of v so you sanitize it in your code to strip any possible code that can cause XSS, cross site scripting. Prepared queries will protect against sql inject by escaping special characters such as ' and ". You are still getting the benefit of caching on your database side for that query. If the query is run again on your database with the same parameters, the database engine will try to use the result that's cached. If it's not cached it will fetch the results again.